# Construct a matrix whose column space contains vectors (1, 1, 0) & (0, 0, 1) and row space contains vectors (2, 5) & (1, 2).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've tried solving it by putting the vectors (1, 1, 0) & (0, 0, 1) as columns in a 3 by 2 matrix and then applying column operations on it to achieve the two vectors (2, 5) & (1, 2) to be in two of the rows of this matrix but so far I couldn't find any satisfying answer.

Is it possible?
How do I find it? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the matrix as $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

$(1, 1, 0)=1.C_1+0.C_2$

$(0, 0, 1)=0.C_1+1.C_2$

$(2, 5)=0.R_1+2.R_2+5.R_3$

$(1, 2)=0.R_1+1.R_2+2.R_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you said you can take 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 \\
    1       & 0 \\
    0       & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and then $Row(a) = span\{(1,0), (0, 1)\}$ is the entire space, so it contains $(1,2)$ and $(2, 5)$